# How to hide bottomAppBar when scrolling down using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple `BottomAppBar` as the below code:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 10,
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    minWidth: 155,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        // currentScreen =
                        //     Chat(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                        currentTab = 1;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.home,
                          color: currentTab == 1 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Home',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 1 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),

              // Right Tab bar icons

              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    minWidth: 60,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        // currentScreen =
                        //     Settings(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                        currentTab = 3;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.view_list,
                          color: currentTab == 3 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Property List',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 3 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    minWidth: 77,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        // currentScreen =
                        //     Settings(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                        currentTab = 4;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.location_searching,
                          color: currentTab == 4 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Map',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 4 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Edited:

this is my whole code:

```
// import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

import '../providers/properties.dart';
import '../providers/cities.dart';
import '../providers/property.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
// import './model/homelist.dart';
// import './providers/properties.dart';
// import './providers/properties.dart';
import '../widgets/properties_grid.dart';
// import '../providers/property.dart';
import '../app_theme.dart';
// import './widgets/property_item.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int currentTab = 0;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool _showBottomBar = true;

  _scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.reverse) {
      setState(() {
        _showBottomBar = false;
      });
    } else if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.forward) {
      setState(() {
        _showBottomBar = true;
      });
    }
  }
  // final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();
  var _showOnlyFavorites = false;
  // List<HomeList> homeList = HomeList.homeList;
  AnimationController animationController;
  bool multiple = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> getData() async {
    await Future<dynamic>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 0));
    return true;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final properties = Provider.of<Properties>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 10,
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    minWidth: 155,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        // currentScreen =
                        //     Chat(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                        currentTab = 1;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.home,
                          color: currentTab == 1 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Home',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 1 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),

              // Right Tab bar icons

              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    minWidth: 60,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        // currentScreen =
                        //     Settings(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                        currentTab = 3;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.view_list,
                          color: currentTab == 3 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Property List',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 3 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    minWidth: 77,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        // currentScreen =
                        //     Settings(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                        currentTab = 4;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.location_searching,
                          color: currentTab == 4 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Map',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 4 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: AppTheme.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder<bool>(
            future: getData(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const SizedBox();
              } else {
                return Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      appBar(),
                      Expanded(
                        child: FutureBuilder<bool>(
                          future: getData(),
                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
                            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                              return const SizedBox();
                            } else {
                              return ChangeNotifierProvider(
                                create: (context) => Properties(),
                                child: PropertiesGrid(_showOnlyFavorites),
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget appBar() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: AppBar().preferredSize.height,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 8),
            child: Container(
              width: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              height: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                child:
                    Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png', fit: BoxFit.contain),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 8),
            child: Container(
              width: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              height: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: InkWell(
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.circular(AppBar().preferredSize.height),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.location_on,
                    color: AppTheme.dark_grey,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      multiple = !multiple;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

## Edited 2

```
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      extendBody: true,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        child: _showBottomBar
            ? BottomAppBar(
                elevation: 0,
                shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
                notchMargin: 10,
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          MaterialButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            minWidth: 155,
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                // currentScreen =
                                //     Chat(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                                currentTab = 1;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.home,
                                  color: currentTab == 1
                                      ? Colors.blue
                                      : Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Home',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: currentTab == 1
                                        ? Colors.blue
                                        : Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),

                      // Right Tab bar icons

                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          MaterialButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            minWidth: 60,
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                // currentScreen =
                                //     Settings(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                                currentTab = 3;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.view_list,
                                  color: currentTab == 3
                                      ? Colors.blue
                                      : Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Property List',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: currentTab == 3
                                        ? Colors.blue
                                        : Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          MaterialButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            minWidth: 77,
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                // currentScreen =
                                //     Settings(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                                currentTab = 4;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.location_searching,
                                  color: currentTab == 4
                                      ? Colors.blue
                                      : Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Map',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: currentTab == 4
                                        ? Colors.blue
                                        : Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: AppTheme.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder<bool>(
            future: getData(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const SizedBox();
              } else {
                return Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      appBar(),
                      Expanded(
                        child: FutureBuilder<bool>(
                          future: getData(),
                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
                            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                              return const SizedBox();
                            } else {
                              return ChangeNotifierProvider(
                                create: (context) => Properties(),
                                child: PropertiesGrid(_showOnlyFavorites),
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

I need now to hide this bottom bar when scrolling down... Is there's a way to do this with a simple animation??...

also I have at the center a floating action button so if there's a possibility to hide this `FloatButton` with the bar while scrolling down??...

Hope some one help me to solve this issue...

Answer (score 1):

ScrollController is used for managing scroll direction of the widget, which have a callback like

```
_scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
```

**Example:**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int currentTab = 1;

  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool _showBottomBar = true;

  _scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.reverse) {
      setState(() {
        _showBottomBar = false;
      });
    } else if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.forward) {
      setState(() {
        _showBottomBar = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        height: 60.0,
        child: _showBottomBar? BottomAppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          notchMargin: 10,
          child: Container(
            height: 60,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    MaterialButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      minWidth: 155,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          // currentScreen =
                          //     Chat(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                          currentTab = 1;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.home,
                            color: currentTab == 1 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Home',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: currentTab == 1 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),

                // Right Tab bar icons

                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    MaterialButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      minWidth: 60,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          // currentScreen =
                          //     Settings(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                          currentTab = 3;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.view_list,
                            color: currentTab == 3 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Property List',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: currentTab == 3 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    MaterialButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      minWidth: 77,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          // currentScreen =
                          //     Settings(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                          currentTab = 4;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.location_searching,
                            color: currentTab == 4 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Map',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: currentTab == 4 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ): Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
            controller: _scrollController,
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 120,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  )
                ],
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank a lot for your help... but If I have an another initState for an animation could you please check the full code I have edited my post thank you :)

Comment: I also tried your code but it doen't work :( I appretiate that you checl last edit :), as I need to hide the float action button as well

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the ScrollNotification class:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollNotification-class.html